# can i make a unix based os with c#

Tags: c#, .net, unix, linux-kernel, operating-system

I want to make a OS for myself, but i just know c# and a bit of python. So my question was that can i make a Unix based OS with c#. I am really interesting in  operating systems. I tried to make it with google's help but they just tell to make Unix/Linux based OS with c/c++ and not c# .  I don't want to use cosmos or compact etc , as i think Unix is more advance . So can you please tell me that can i make an OS in c# using Unix kernel . If no , then what are some other good kernels to work on to make a OS in c# . i will be really thankful for your answer ..

Comment: No, you can't you need a native languaje, one that can be directly converted to ASM so the computar can load it. C# is a managed language which is executed through a virtual machine and that virtual machine already needs an OS.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, why not? Of course you will need to use assembly and C/C++ to code the hardware specific (low level) parts.

Please take a look at **Singularity**: it's a research operating system written in C#. See details [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/singularity/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(operating_system)).

I don't understand your statement about Unix being more advance. Modern operating systems (Windows, MacOS, Linux) are at least as advance as Unix.

I advice you to learn more on operating systems. Then start with a simple OS in assembly (like [this](http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/write-your-own-os.html)). Then continue with C/C++ and C#.